# Retrieve user input and use different fetch url accordingly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-hooks

Fetching and displaying data in a table like view is working good.

I do have 3 labels with fields-> "user no, id number and lic no". I want to retrieve value input fields and call different fetch url accordingly. For ex: if user enters some particular user no, then i need to retrive that "user no" and call different `fetch` url in this method `fetchTableData()`. Could you please tell me, How do I retrieve value from the field and get that value into `fetchTableData()` function where i need to redirect URL based on the user input ?

```
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component"
import { useState, useEffect } from "react"

function App() {
    const [data, setData] = useState([])
    const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false)
    const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10)
    const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

    const columns = [
        {
            name: "Date",
            selector: (row) => row.memberno,
            width: "120px",
            wrap: true
        },
        {
            name: "Title",
            selector: (row) => row.title,
            wrap: true
        },
        {
            name: "ID Number",
            selector: (row) => row.dmnumber,
            wrap: true
        },
        {
            name: "License no",
            selector: (row) => row.documentid,
            wrap: true
        },
        {
            name: "Contact",
            selector: (row) => row.marketingcontact,
            wrap: true
        }
    ]

    useEffect(() => {
        fetchTableData()
    }, [])
    
    const handleSubmit = (e) => {
        e.preventDefault();
        setShow(true);
    };
    async function fetchTableData() {
        setLoading(true)
        const header = new Headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });

        // here i will be using different fetch url based on user inputs value for "user no or id number and lic no" 
        const response = await fetch('http://ec2-3-145-165-206.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080/searchAll', { header: header })

        const users = await response.json()
        setData(users)
        setLoading(false)
    }

  return (
      <div className="wrapper">
        <h1> User Data Repo </h1>
        <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
          <fieldset>
            <label>
              <p>User Number:</p>
              <input name="userno" />
            </label>
              <label>
                  <p>ID Number:</p>
                  <input name="idnumber" />
              </label>
              <label>
                  <p>Lic Number:</p>
                  <input name="licnumber" />
              </label>
          </fieldset>

            <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
                Submit
            </button>
        </form>

          <DataTable
              //title="Data"
              columns={columns}
              data={show ? data : []}
              progressPending={loading}
              pagination
          />
      </div>
  )
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't know well what you are saying. But in my opinion, you can do like the following code:

```
import DataTable from "react-data-table-component";
import { useState, useEffect } from "react";

function App() {
  const [data, setData] = useState([]);
  const [loading, setLoading] = useState(false);
  const [perPage, setPerPage] = useState(10);
  const [show, setShow] = useState(false);

  const [userno, setUserno] = useState("");
  const [idnumber, setIdnumber] = useState("");
  const [licnumber, setLicnumber] = useState("");

  const columns = [
    {
      name: "Date",
      selector: (row) => row.memberno,
      width: "120px",
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Title",
      selector: (row) => row.title,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "ID Number",
      selector: (row) => row.dmnumber,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "License no",
      selector: (row) => row.documentid,
      wrap: true,
    },
    {
      name: "Contact",
      selector: (row) => row.marketingcontact,
      wrap: true,
    },
  ];

  useEffect(() => {
    fetchTableData();
  }, []);

  const handleSubmit = (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    setShow(true);
    fetchTableData(userno, idnumber, licnumber); // pass the input values
  };
  async function fetchTableData() {
    setLoading(true);
    const header = new Headers({ "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" });

    const server_url =
      "http://ec2-3-145-165-206.us-east-2.compute.amazonaws.com:8080";
    let url = `${server_url}/searchAll`; // default url
    if (userno) {
      // if user no is provided, use this url
      url = `${server_url}/searchByUserNo/${userno}`;
    } else if (idnumber) {
      // if id number is provided, use this url
      url = `${server_url}/searchByIdNumber/${idnumber}`;
    } else if (licnumber) {
      // if lic number is provided, use this url
      url = `${server_url}/searchByLicNumber/${licnumber}`;
    }
    const response = await fetch(url, { header: header });
    const users = await response.json();
    setData(users);
    setLoading(false);
  }

  return (
    <div className="wrapper">
      <h1> User Data Repo </h1>
      <form onSubmit={handleSubmit}>
        <fieldset>
          <label>
            <p>User Number:</p>
            <input
              name="userno"
              value={userno}
              onChange={(e) => setUserno(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            <p>ID Number:</p>
            <input
              name="idnumber"
              value={idnumber}
              onChange={(e) => setIdnumber(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
          <label>
            <p>Lic Number:</p>
            <input
              name="licnumber"
              value={licnumber}
              onChange={(e) => setLicnumber(e.target.value)}
            />
          </label>
        </fieldset>

        <button type="submit" onClick={handleSubmit}>
          Submit
        </button>
      </form>

      <DataTable
        //title="Data"
        columns={columns}
        data={show ? data : []}
        progressPending={loading}
        pagination
      />
    </div>
  );
}

export default App;
```

Of course, I may not understand you so my answer may be incorrect.

Answer (score 1):

First, you don't want to use the same function, leave `fetchTableData` for the first render an create another function to achieve this behavior:

```js
async function fetParticularData() {
    //...
}
```

second in React we usually use `onChange` to update a state then give this latter as `value` to the input, so we can create only one state for all the inputs it is an object:

```js
const [form, setForm ] = useState({
 userno: "",
 idnumber: "",
 licnumber: ""
})
```

we bind it to our inputs:

```html
<fieldset>
  <label>
    <p>User Number:</p>
    <input
      name="userno"
      value={form.userno} 
      onChange={handleFormInputChange} />
  </label>
  <label>
    <p>ID Number:</p>
    <input
      name="idnumber"
      value={form.idnumber}
      onChange={handleFormInputChange}
    />
  </label>
  <label>
    <p>Lic Number:</p>
    <input
      name="licnumber"
      value={form.licnumber}
      onChange={handleFormInputChange}
    />
  </label>
</fieldset>
```

the `handleFormInputChange` function updates the `form` state based on `e.target.name`, it is the easiest way **but we have to give the input name the same value of the coresponding property in the state object**:

```js
function handleFormInputChange(e) {
  setForm((prev) => {
    return { ...prev, [e.target.name]: e.target.value };
  });
}
```

now when you want to fetch particular data you just call the `fetParticularData` function, you can have access to the inputs values from there:

```js
async function fetParticularData(){
  console.log("userno: ", form.userno);
  console.log("idnumber", form.idnumber);
  console.log("licnumber", form.licnumber);
  setLoading(true)
  // based on thesevalue you can create your logic then fetch data
  setData(users)
  setLoading(false)
}
```

or call it inside the submit function if you want:

```js
const handleSubmit = (e) => {
  e.preventDefault();
  setShow(true);
  fetParticularData()
};
```